# Allow user to select csv's VBA not working

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to modify the following code so that two things happen:

1) The user is able to select the csv's they want in a folder
2)Keep the header for the first csv only and keep the body for the rest of Csvs

How would I go about this in the following code? I keep receiving an error currently when I run this code.

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()

    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [CSV Consolidation]"


    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)


    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then xSht.UsedRange.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")

    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        Columns(1).Insert xlShiftToRight
        Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        xWb.Close False
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


    Range("A1:R1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("L1").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False





    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files csv", , "Team"
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of error and when you receive?

Comment: why not make sure your template already has headers so you never have to grab them. Otherwise you will need to add another loop and or check to do this in code. Makes more sense to just save a template with headers already

Comment: Pm Duda, the code skips to the errorhandler.

Comment: urdearboy, that's a good point that I haven't thought of. The problem is that I don't see the headers changing for these CSV files but it is a possibility so I need it to be a little more dynamic.

Comment: You need to disable error handling while debugging. Remove `On Error GoTo` and re-run

Comment: The error I receive now is :

"Bad File Name or Number" and the code in question is:

xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\" & "*.csv")

Comment: Because xStrPath already contains file address. So you are trying to open something like *C:/myfile.csv\*.csv*

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little starter for you.

It grab files without your error and then you can do what you want.

```
Sub ImportCSVsWithReference()

    Dim xSht  As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String

    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [CSV Consolidation]"

    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    If MsgBox("Clear the existing sheet before importing?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then xSht.UsedRange.Clear
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

     Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(xStrPath)
     MsgBox "Opened " & xStrPath & " for headers"

     'Do your work with headers here with xWb as workbook with code
     xWb.Close False


    For Each vrtSelectedItem In xFileDialog.SelectedItems

        Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
        MsgBox "Opened " & vrtSelectedItem & " for content"
        'Do your work with content here with xWb as workbook with code
        xWb.Close False
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True



End Sub
```